# find a href with a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I have an array called "selectMe" formed by a variable wich contains a string such as: 12P, 5B, 10C, etc., this is the "href" value of a hyperlink and I need to find and add the class "selected" to the ones inside this array. To break the array I have:

```
function selectPrevious(selections){
    // split into array
    var selectMe = selections.split(", ")
    for (var i = 0; i < selectMe.length; i++){
        $('#theater a').search(selectMe[i]).addClass('selected');
    }
}
```

I've tried doing `find()` instead of `search()` as well as many other iterations but still haven't been able to accomplish what I want, how can I do it?

**EDIT**

Using one of the answers provided here I have changed it to this:

```
function selectPrevious(selections){
            // split into array
            if(typeof selections !== "undefined"){
                    var selectMe = selections.split(", ");
                for (var i = 0; i < selectMe.length; i++){
                    $('#theater a[href*='+selectMe[i]+']').addClass('selected');
                }
            }
        }
```

I had to add the "if(typeof selections !== "undefined")" because otherwise it was throwing me errors on IE. Anyway, I still can't add the class "selected" to the values in the array, am I missing something? or did I do something wrong?

Comment: what is there in `selections` variable?

Comment: selections is an array containing values like: 12P, 5B, 10C, etc

Comment: and what is 12P or 5B or 10C to any hyperlink? is it any kind of attribute? or is it the id of hyperlink?

Comment: If `selections` is already an array why are you using `.split` on it?

Comment: sorry, I sould've stated it. It's the "href" value of a hyperlink

Comment: just edited the post again, sorry I posted it wrong the first time

Comment: could you please also post the html here for better understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
function selectPrevious(selections) {
    // split into array
    var selectMe = selections.split(", ")
    for (var i = 0; i < selectMe.length; i++){
        $('#theater').find('a[href*='+selectMe[i]+']').addClass('selected');
    }
}
```

Comment: I had an extra ; in an if...after I took it away everything worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector for find() is wrong. And there are no `search()` in jQuery.
Instead of `$('#theater a').search(selectMe[i])` use `$('#theater a[href*='+selectMe[i]+']')`